# ¿Qué es "román paladino"? ¿Cómo pasó "paladino" a significar "claro" si viene de "palaciego"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, locuciones, latín

Hace un rato el político Pablo Iglesias [colgó en Twitter](https://twitter.com/Pablo_Iglesias_/status/930714966755332096) un vídeo con su interpelación al presidente del Gobierno de España, Mariano Rajoy. En él dice esto en un momento dado:

> (...) le voy a leer la definición jurídica de prueba indiciaria: prueba indiciaria es aquella que permite dar por acreditados en un proceso judicial unos hechos a partir de estimar probados otros hechos relacionados de los que cabe deducir razonablemente la certeza o acreditación de los primeros. En **román paladino**, señor Rajoy, han quedado acreditadas dos cosas: uno, que usted cobró sobresueldos ilegales regularmente al menos desde 1997 hasta 2008; dos, que usted mintió cuando afirmó en sede judicial que jamás cobró sobresueldos.

El término *román paladino* lo describe el DLE como:

> [**román**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WdO8jFu)
>   Del fr. *roman*.
>
> **román paladino**
>   1. m. Lenguaje llano y claro.

Por lo que en la frase de arriba funciona como conector entre una definición jurídica algo compleja y una explicación más llana y directa.

Tirando del hilo veo que *paladino* se define así:

> [**paladino<sup>1</sup>, na**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RVN7iry%7CRVOE10g)
>   Del lat. *palatīnus* 'palaciego', con influencia de *palam* 'abiertamente, públicamente'.
>   1. adj. Público, claro y patente.
>   a paladinas
>   1. loc. adv. desus. paladinamente.
>   román paladino
>
> **paladino<sup>2</sup>**
>   Del it. paladino, y este del lat. palatīnus 'palaciego'.
>   1. m. [paladín](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RVJuXin).
>
> > [**paladín**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RVJuXin)
> >     Del it. paladino, y este del lat. palatīnus 'palaciego'.
> >     1. m. Caballero fuerte y valeroso que, voluntario en la guerra, se distingue por sus hazañas.
> >     2. m. Defensor denodado de alguien o algo.

Lo que me lleva a "descubrir" que *paladín* quiere decir *llano, claro* a través de una raíz latina que indica *palaciego*, junto con otra que quiere decir *abierta o públicamente*.

Entonces la pregunta es: ¿qué influencia tiene la raíz *palaciega* en convertir algo *paladino* en algo claro, llano?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hum, complicado. Según el *Diccionario de autoridades*, la etimología de la palabra era que venía del latín *Palam*, y no consideraba otras etimologías. Define este diccionario la palabra como "público, claro y patente". Pero todos los diccionarios anteriores la definen como sinónimo de *paladín*, que sí que viene del latín *palatīnus* ('palaciego'). ¿Es posible que sea al revés? ¿Que venga de *palam* con influencia de *palatīnus*?

El caso es que estoy viendo textos de hasta el siglo XIII que usan *paladino* en la forma actual:

> *Donquas, el alcalde toiller deue de su oreilla tal conseillo, diziendo li: "Si algo quieres dizir, dime paladino"...* (c1250)

Vamos, prácticamente está diciendo "si quieres hablar, habla claro". O este otro texto de Alfonso X:

> *Porque este nuestro libro sea mas paladino & se pueda meior entender.* (1279)

Y ya si lo quieres flipar del todo, observa el siguiente texto:

> *Quiero fer una prosa en román paladino
>
>   en qual suele el pueblo fablar con so vecino,
>
>   ca non so tan letrado por fer otro latino,
>
>   bien valdrá, como creo, un vaso de bon vino.*
>
> Gonzalo de Berceo, "Vida de Santo Domingo de Silos", c1236 (España).

La mismita expresión que usamos hoy día, usada para expresar el deseo de escribir en lenguaje llano (me ha encantado: "el que el pueblo habla con su vecino"). Y no encuentro casos anteriores a este al buscar simplemente la palabra *paladino*, por lo que este texto puede constituir perfectamente el origen de la expresión, aunque sí he encontrado este otro texto (ligeramente corregido para facilitar su lectura) que usa la forma adverbial:

> Omne que fuere enemiztado, tal que ni va ni viene a conçeio ni a mercado ni ande por la villa paladinamientre, o omne flaco por vejez o linençioso... (c1196)

En este texto se hace referencia a las personas que no pueden andar *paladinamente* por la villa, es decir, de forma pública como lo haría alguien sin cargo de conciencia (es decir, como un *paladín*).

Este texto puede aclarar que, tal y como dice el DLE hoy día, la palabra *paladino* sí pueda tener la misma etimología que *paladín*, entendiendo el contexto en el que usó en los primeros escritos que documentan la expresión *paladinamente*: se camina paladinamente cuando no tienes nada que esconder ni de qué avergonzarte. Es decir, mostrándote en público cual paladín. De ahí seguramente apareció el adjetivo *paladino* por influencia de *palam* para expresar la idea de hacer algo en público, de forma clara, sin nada que ocultar. También, según otras fuentes, *paladino* en aquella época vendría a significar "manifiesto, conocido por todos". Supongo que igual que los paladines, que serían figuras conocidas por todos.

La influencia de *palam* se nota también en otras palabras, como *[espaladinar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GTQLJCb)*, voz en desuso que equivale a *explicar con claridad*, es decir, "hacer algo claro", y que se usó por las mismas fechas:

> *... por fazerles bien e merced, toviemos por bien de espaladinar aquellas dubdas de guisa que se pudiessen bien entender, e de mejorar e de endereçar...* (1263)

Una expresión curiosa que también he encontrado en textos del siglo XIII:

> *Á furto ó paladino*: a escondidas o a las claras; en público o en secreto.

Answer (score 3):

En la época de Gonzalo de Berceo el pueblo ya no entendía latín y hablaba en romance, así como también lo hacían los nobles, es decir, en los palacios. A diferencia de entre los eclesiásticos que eran los únicos que seguían hablando en latín. Por ello, "roman paladino" en el texto de Gonzalo de Berceo hace referencia al lenguaje que hablaban los nobles, es decir, lo que no era latín, es decir, castellano.
Puesto que el latín solo lo hablaban los curas, se convirtió en una lengua de pocos, oscura, no clara, no abierta a todos. Por eso "paladino" también pasó a tener significado de "público" o "abierto", es decir, lo común, lo que usaba el común de los mortales, el vulgo.

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://etimologias.dechile.net/%3Fpaladi.n&ved=2ahUKEwjP5M-B_Lr_AhX4UaQEHZDHCzQQFnoECA0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw1srq-Qc4uODbQIVToACFPT