# Interpretación de la estrofa "quiero fer una prosa en román paladino" de "Vida de Santo Domingo de Silos" de Gonzalo de Berceo

Tags: significado, poesía, interpretación, español-medieval

Buscando la respuesta a la pregunta *[¿Qué es "román paladino"? ¿Cómo pasó "paladino" a significar "claro" si viene de "palaciego"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23219/12637)* llegué al siguiente poema:

> *Quiero fer una prosa en román paladino
>
>   en qual suele el pueblo fablar con so vecino,
>
>   ca non so tan letrado por fer otro latino,
>
>   bien valdrá, como creo, un vaso de bon vino.*
>
> Gonzalo de Berceo, "Vida de Santo Domingo de Silos", c1236 (España).

La interpretación que le doy al poema es: "quiero escribir en lenguaje llano, el que habla el pueblo, porque no tengo conocimientos para hacerlo en latín"... y me falla el último verso. No entiendo la relación entre esto y un vaso de buen vino.

¿Qué me está fallando en la interpretación?

---

Esta estrofa es la segunda del poema completo, que se puede leer en la [biblioteca virtual Miguel de Cervantes](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/portales/gonzalo_de_berceo/obra-visor/vida-de-sancto-domingo-de-silos-vida-de-sancta-oria-virgen--0/html/00048970-82b2-11df-acc7-002185ce6064_2.html#I_0_).

Comment: En mi caso (y creo que en el de otras personas de mi edad e incluso más jóvenes) el proceso fue el inverso: a través del poema de Gonzalo de Berceo tuve conocimiento de que "román paladino" es "lenguaje llano y claro"

Comment: La relación, entiendo yo, es con el primer verso,  mientras el  2.º y 3.º son un inciso. Es decir, lo que vale un buen vino , es hacer prosa en román paladino, valga el pareado, no que sea poco letrado (uy, otro).

Answer (score 5):

Hay que ver todo el poema para entenderlo y no solo un verso. Es un poema que narra la vida de Santo Domingo de Silos. Y lo escribe en el idioma que en ese momento hablaba el pueblo llano (de esta manera la gente humilde lo entendería) y no en el culto latín.
Un vaso de buen vino es toda la recompensa que pide por su trabajo. En la Rioja es típico después del trabajo bien hecho brindar con un buen vino.

Answer (score 3):

Mi opinión es que simplemente está dándole un valor a su poema a pesar de no estar escrito en el idioma que en aquella época era considerado culto (latín).

En los tres primeros versos está justificandose por utilizar el latín vulgar y en el último está añadiendo que no utilizar latín no le quita al poema todo el valor, al menos un vaso de buen vino valdrá.

Hay que tener en cuenta que la palabra que mejor cuadra semánticamente en un poema puede no cuadrar rítmicamente. Cuando hay que elegir entre semántica y ritmo, no es raro que muchos poetas se decanten por el ritmo.

Answer (score 2):

La expresión "*vaso de bon vino*" con la que Berceo termina su estrofa no refleja sino una influencia del mester de juglaría: los juglares, al final de la recitación de sus poemas épicos solían pedir una recompensa que no siempre era pecuniaria; la mayoría de las veces era para comer o beber. De este modo, Berceo se acerca más aún al pueblo al que pretende llegar con su obra al igual que los juglares. De ahí el uso del "*román paladino*". Por ello es conocido dicho autor también con el sobrenombre de "juglar a lo divino".